# How to get the index with jQuery Sortable

Tags: jquery

With the third party plugin, [jQuery Sortable](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) how can we get the index of the item that is last dragged and sorted?

If I have 3 items like below, 3 `<tr>` rows with a `<td>` block for each value...

```
mom  1
dad  2
baby 3
```

...and I drag row `baby 3` up to be the first row, what callback process must I do to show that it is now index 1.

Instructions on how to do this was not documented on the page.  Which is why I am requesting for an educated suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`onDrop`](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#docs) callback to refer to the dragged item and get it's index:

```
$("ol.example").sortable({
    'onDrop': function($item, container, _super, event) {
      console.log($item.index());
    }
  });
```

---

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gz2cd5qg/)

Comment: Perfect and thank you.  I was looking for this example on the main site but had trouble seeing that we can that with the examples.  This helps me see the simplicity of capturing an index.